# Checking if a certain key is being pressed

Tags: python, pynput

i'm fairly new to python. This is my code till now.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


counta = 0

def on_press(key):


    if key == a:
        print("a is pressed")
        global counta
        counta += 1
        print(counta)

    else:
        print("keyboard pressed")


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I want to check if the Key that is pressed is the lower a. But till now it prints out "keyboard pressed" no matter if i press the 'a' key or any other key.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Your code can't run as presented. `if key == a:` won't work because the variable `a` isn't defined. Did you mean to compare with the string `'a'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `key.char` attribute and also use quotes to `'a'`

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

counta = 0

def on_press(key):

    if key.char == 'a':
        print("a is pressed")
        global counta
        counta += 1
        print(counta)

    else:
        print("keyboard pressed")


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Try to use the debugger it will help you a lot.